# Create new ParseUser from facebook data

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm developing app where user can sign up filling all required info by them self or adding information like email, profile picture from facebook.

I followed this tutorial: https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-android

So far I have managed that all input fields have filled when user taps on Facebook login button eaven profile picture. But to create new parseUser I need to insert all values like this

```
                                ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                                newUser.setUsername(email);
                                newUser.setPassword(password);
                                newUser.setEmail(email);
                                newUser.put("name", name);
                                newUser.put("phone", phone);
```

to add profile picture to the user I need to get Byte[] and put it in the newUser. But I don't know how to get from facebookId to Byte[] because in this tutorial I got facebook user's profiel picture from facebookId.

code sample where I make request:

```
private void makeRequest() {
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        userProfile.put("facebookId", user.getId());
                        userProfile.put("name", user.getName());
                        if (user.getLocation().getProperty("name") != null) {
                            userProfile.put("location", (String) user.getLocation().getProperty("name"));
                        }
                        if (user.getProperty("email") != null) {
                            userProfile.put("email",(String) user.getProperty("email"));
                        }
                        if (user.getBirthday() != null) {
                            userProfile.put("birthday",user.getBirthday());
                        }

                        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                        currentUser.put("profile", userProfile);
                        currentUser.saveInBackground();

                        updateprofileinfo();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "json error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }   
                } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                    if ((response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_RETRY)
                            || (response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION)) {
                        Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "invalid fb session", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startLoginActivity();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

and this is code where I got information and fill all the fields whit info from facebook:

```
private void updateprofileinfo() {
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser.get("profile") != null) {
            JSONObject userProfile = currentUser.getJSONObject("profile");
            try {
                if (userProfile.getString("facebookId") != null) {
                    String facebookId = userProfile.get("facebookId").toString();
                    mFbFoto.setProfileId(facebookId);
                } else {
                    mFbFoto.setProfileId(null);
                }
                if (userProfile.getString("name") != null) {
                    mFbName.setText(userProfile.getString("name"));
                } else {
                    mFbName.setText("");
                }
                if (userProfile.getString("email") != null) {
                    mFbEmail.setText(userProfile.getString("email"));
                }
                else {
                    mFbEmail.setText("");
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "error update info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I get from request facebookId and insert it into profilepicture widget but to upload this picture I need to convert it to byte[] and then from byte[] create new ParseFile and then add it to the newUser code, but I don't know how to make byte[] from facebookId.

Any help would be aprreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting Bitmap image from Facebook graph api once permission has been granted

```
URL img_value = null;
         try {
            img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+user.getId()+"/picture?type=large");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         try {
             StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
            Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
            userImage=mIcon1;
            mIcon1=null;
            Log.i(TAG_facebook, "image retrieved from facebook");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For converting Bitmap into bytes[]

```
public byte[] compressAndConvertImageToByteFrom(Bitmap imageBitmap){

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();

}
```

pass this bytes[] to your ParseFile using

```
ParseFile saveImageFile= new ParseFile("profileImage.jpg",signUp_Image_Bytes);
saveUserDetails.put("YourParseImageFileColumnname",saveImageFile);
```